# why imagepng after resize create a black image?

Tags: php, image, transparency

i m trying to resize a image using code:

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr)= getimagesize($_FILES['upload'.$num]['name']);
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['upload'.$num]['name']);
                $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(445,320);
                imagealphablending($thumb, false);
                imagesavealpha($thumb, true);  
                    imagecopyresampled($thumb,$source,0,0,0,0,445,320,$width,$height);
                imagepng($thumb,"../public/img/".$Nome,8);

but the output is always a black image..  anyone know why?
```

Thanks

Comment: @KLVTZ: There is no such thing as incorrect ratio problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES['upload'.$num]['name']` is just filename of uploaded like "flower.jpg" not full path to file.

`$_FILES['upload'.$num]['tmp_name']` is real absolute path to real file uploaded on your server (somewhere in temp directory)

---

Your code should look like this:

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr)= getimagesize($_FILES['upload'.$num]['tmp_name']);
$source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['upload'.$num]['tmp_name']);
```

---

Always try to debug your first. Use functions like `print_r($_FILES)`, `var_dump($_FILES)` to debug your variables.

except issue with `$_FILES` variable, your code should works fine: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YpU80h)

Comment: Tank you for this answer it was very helpful