# Black images after resizing image

Tags: php, thumbnails, image-resizing

I use the below code to create a thumbnail. Its is working perfectly when it is a separate php page. But when i convert it to function and use it in my upload page, it is create black images. Please help

```
$filename='something.jpg'; //filename
 if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('upload/'.$filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif('upload/'.$filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng('upload/'.$filename);
    }
     $nx=400; //size of thumbnail to be create
     $ny=300;
    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);
    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
     $path='upload/';
    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);
    if(!file_exists($path)) {
      if(!mkdir($path)) {
           die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
      } 
       }
     imagejpeg($nm,  $path . $filename);
```

Comment: Maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167958/why-imagepng-after-resize-create-a-black-image

Comment: hehe never seen regex used to match a file extension before.

Comment: using file extensions to determine mime type is not a good idea. the easiest/simplest method is to skip all that logic and simply do `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename))` and let GD do the heavy duty work.

Comment: but the code is working perfect when it is in a single page. The problem occurs only when it is converted as a button